# How to create Win32 HBITMAP from pixelbuffer

Tags: winapi, bitmap

I am try to create an HBITMAP from pixel buffer and display it. Here is my code to create the HBITMAP

```
char buffer[640 * 480 * 3];
memset(buffer, 255, 640 * 480 * 3);
BITMAPINFO bm = { sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),
        640,
        480, 1, 24,
        BI_RGB, 640 * 480 * 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
HBITMAP imageBmp = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &bm, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)buffer, 0, 0);
if (imageBmp == NULL) {
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
    return;
}
```

Here is the code to display it:

```
 HDC imageDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);     // create an offscreen DC
SelectObject(imageDC, imageBmp);  // put the loaded image into our DC
RECT rect;
GetClientRect(hDlg, &rect);
BitBlt(
    hdc,         // tell it we want to draw to the screen
    0, 0,            // as position 0,0 (upper-left corner)
    rect.right - rect.left,   // width of the rect to draw
    rect.bottom - rect.top,   // height of the rect
    imageDC,        // the DC to get the rect from (our image DC)
    0, 0,            // take it from position 0,0 in the image DC
    SRCCOPY         // tell it to do a pixel-by-pixel copy
);
```

I am expecting to see a white image, but what I got was a black window screen. I am pretty sure my display code is correct, but do not know why the code to create HBITMAP was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

`CreateDIBSection` already returns an allocated buffer through the `ppvBits` argument to you, so it overwrites your `buffer` variable. From the docs (emphasis mine):

> ppvBits A pointer to a variable that **receives** a pointer to the
>   location of the DIB bit values.

Fixes required to your code:

- Remove code to create an array.
- Pass the address of a pointer for the `ppvBits` parameter.
- Set the pixels only *after* a successfull call to `CreateDIBSection`.

```cpp
char* buffer = NULL;
BITMAPINFO bm = { sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),
        640,
        480, 1, 24,
        BI_RGB, 640 * 480 * 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
HBITMAP imageBmp = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &bm, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**) &buffer, 0, 0);
if (imageBmp == NULL) {
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
    return;
}
memset(buffer, 255, 640 * 480 * 3);
```

**Note:**

Make sure that in production code, you properly calculate the size by aligning the bitmap width to the next `DWORD` boundary, as described by the article "[DIBs and Their Use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms969901(v=msdn.10))":

> Calculating the size of a bitmap is not difficult:
>
> ```
> biSizeImage = ((((biWidth * biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3) * biHeight
> ```
>
> The crazy roundoffs and shifts account for the bitmap being
>   DWORD-aligned at the end of every scanline.

In your sample, `640 * 480 * 3` gives the correct result only because the width of `640` is already divisable by 4. For a width of `641` your formula would fail, while the formula cited from the article would give the correct result.

Comment: Scanline DWORD alignment?

Comment: @Anders Good suggestion, I will add this when I find some time.

Comment: Hi @zett42, thanks for your post. However, it does not seem to work. After CreateDIBSection, buffer is still 0